# In django how do i keep the user logged in in websocket

Tags: django

In my django project, I have a page that will send http request only when it is opened for the first time, after that a websocket connection is established and all data is passed through websocket. In order to keep the user logged in, I added this logic in the sent data method. During the test, it seems to have worked, and the expiration time of the session has always been what I expected. But after a period of time (more than SESSION_COOKIE_AGE), I refreshed the page and found that I was redirected to the login interface.

```
    async def send_data(self, event=None):
        data = event['message']
        data = self.request_data(data)
        self.scope["session"].set_expiry(SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)
        await sync_to_async(self.scope["session"].save)()
        dic = {'status': '1', 'msg': 'success', 'data': data}
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(dic))
```

I want to know why this is happening and how can I go about it